# Several FlipClock counters and different CSS styles for each one of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flipclock

I have several(more than 1) [flipclock](http://flipclockjs.com/) counters on a single page. I need to change some CSS styles for each one of them. If i change styles in flipclock.css file, it affects all the flipclock counters i have on a page.

I read the [API](http://flipclockjs.com/api) documentation and i found a property that may help called 'classes' but i didn't find any examples of using it.

Please, help me change CSS styles for different flipclock counters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap each clock in a div with a class then use that to style each of the clocks.

```
<div class="blue-clock">
    <div class="your-clock"></div>
</div>
```

Or add a new class or id to each clock like this.

```
<div id="id-here" class="your-clock blue-clock"></div>
```

Then in your css use.

```
.blue-clock {color: blue;}
```